# How do I use jQuery mobile popup?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to using the JQuery Mobile Popup from a callback function of an ajax post. My callback function has data called "msg" which is a string, typically saying "Save Succesful". Any examples out there that allow me to open and close either a popup or a dialog with that message? Here is what I have so far:

```
$.post('/Home/SaveSomething', { data: someData },
                function (msg) {
                    //OPEN THE DIALOG
                });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Would it not be possible to simply use an `alert('Save Successful')`? Or do you need some other custom dialog?

Comment: The problem with using an alert is that I cannot resize it on a mobile browser. The sizing just doesn't work. And the mobile dialog looks a lot nicer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('/Home/SaveSomething',
       { data: someData },
                function (msg) {
                    //OPEN THE DIALOG

                     // you can use alert 
                    alert(msg);
                    // or for custom popup need to use css and jquery coding

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="popup-message" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="a" class="ui-content">
          <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="remove" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    </div>
```

Have a empty popup container for the message as above and use container's id to fill data from the ajax success function as below

```
$.post('/Home/SaveSomething', { data: someData },
    function (msg) {

    $('#popup-message').text(msg); //fill the data here
    $('#popup-message').popup("open"); // open the popup
});
```